# PostgreSQL vs MySQL when tying into an android/iphone app

Tags: iphone, android, mysql, postgresql

I'm looking at the cost of using MySQL commercially and have decided for the time being that I may be able to use PostgreSQL instead.

However.....I am not sure if it is compatible with everything that I need to use with the system we are setting up.

I have an application that we are running on both android and Iphone and will be sending lots of data and requesting lots at the same time.

So my question to the community on here is does anyone have any experience in using PostgreSQL in conjunction with android/iphone applications that will be making lots of queries?

Also has anyone here used both PostgreSQL and MySQL and decided to go with one over the other and if so why did you make the decision you did.

Comment: Are you talking about running the DB server on the phone or do you want to simply connect from an app to a backend server?

Comment: Yes I want to be able to talk to the backend server from the device and have the device pull the data as well. This will be happening at a fairly high rate of traffic at a certain point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Denis: PostgreSQL is a good choice and is definitely a lot stronger on the SQL feature side than any other open source DBMS (and rivals the "big ones" as well).

MySQL has been easier to setup in a high-availability (master/slave) environment but the game has changed with 9.0 and will change even more with 9.1 and synchronous replication (which is more or less the same as Oracle offers with it's data guard).

Any load balancing of write access across multiple nodes requires not so trivial 3rd party tools, but then PostgreSQL scales quite well on a single server provided you have decent hardware. Most importantly **lost** of disks in a high-end RAID system (but that is true for all DB server)

We are using PostgreSQL as a backend for several high traffic web-shops and a big portal. All of them having > 1000 concurrent users in average. Peeks are even higher. The shops don't write too much, but the portal is 50% write and 50% read.

MySQL is a good choice as well, but just like Denis I always find myself handcuffed due to several missing SQL features.

Comment: So are you saying that PostgreSQL is a little trickier to use in a server cluster environment? If I did go with PostgreSQL on the clusters I have what kind of 3rd party tools would I be looking at.

Comment: It's a bit trickier if you want to do *load balancing* in a cluster. It's very easy to setup a fail-over cluster for high availability. For load balancing you would need to look at pgbouncer, pg-pool, bucardo or sky tools.

Comment: Hey thank you very much for the info. I definitely have been looking at load balancing through different hardware and software sets but I havent decided on just one strategy. Ill probably be back on here asking about that in another month :p

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I always go with PostgreSQL when I can. MySQL is, in my experience, far too prone to data corruption and lacks many a feature I've come to never do without: array types, full text search with an ACID compliant storage engine, window functions, with statements, etc. Plus, Postgres' tends to find much better query plans than MySQL.

If your app is going to live on the iOS/Android device, that said, use neither. SQLite was designed to live in such embedded systems, it handles simple read/write statements quite well, and (in the case of iOS anyway) it's pre-installed on every device.

Comment: The app will live on the mobile devices and a lot of data will live in a sqlite db on the phones but the data will also be sent to a db on a server where it will be available to other users to see as well.

Comment: The app will live on the mobile devices and a lot of data will live in a sqlite db on the phones but the data will also be sent to a db on a server where it will be available to other users to see as well.  Users will basically be sending and receiving data from the device to the server and back so I need a database that will allow me to send and receive data back and forth from mobile to server and back and also handle high volume traffic. There is also a website that will be pulling info from the db as well.

Comment: In that case, go with PostgreSQL. It can handle concurrent writes much better than MySQL, and writes will be your bottleneck at one point or another. Plus, it now has built-in replication.